# How to prevent segue transition when table view is editing in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, selection, editing

I'm creating a Notes app clone based on the iOS Notes app (for a tutorial's challenge). I'm using the `isEditing` functionality to delete rows in the table view.
The first screen is connected to the second with a storyboard segue but if I am editing (that is, with the empty circles to the left of the rows), tapping on any row both selects and activates the transition.
How can I avoid this?

I added an `if isEditing { return }` call inside the segue, inside the `didSelectRowAt` (which then I removed) but nothing of this works. The transition still happens regardless.

This is the `setEditing` one:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    tableView.setEditing(tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    toolbarItems?[1].isEnabled.toggle()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?[1].isEnabled.toggle()
}
```

There is no other editing code apart from the button creation code
`let editButton = editButtonItem`

The rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/Cellomaster87/ClonedNotes).

Checking also with a Ray Wenderlich tutorial (the Checklist app) I would expect everything to work just fine but I get the transition triggered when "edit mode" is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in your view controller, and have it return `false` if you don't want the segue to be performed.